# ASP.NET MVC: Values are null when they reach the Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I have the following Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateSupport(CreateSupport model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && (model.Description != null))
        {
            model.CreatedById = UserId;
            model.ModifiedById = UserId;
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

I have the following view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateSupport", "Support", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "req" } })
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject)
        </div>

        <div class="support-form-left">

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BrowserInfo, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "req" } })
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BrowserInfo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BrowserInfo)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="support-form-right">

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DatabaseVersion, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "req" } })
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DatabaseVersion)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DatabaseVersion)
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="clearFloat"></div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "req" } })
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <div class="actionButtons">
            <button id="btnCancel" class="myButtonCancel">Cancel</button>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="myButton" />
        </div>
        @if (ViewBag.SuccessMessage != null)
        {
            <div>
                <label style="color: red;">@ViewBag.SuccessMessage</label>
            </div>
        }
    </fieldset>

}
```

Here's the Model:

```
public class CreateSupport : SupportTicket
{
    public CreateSupport()
    {
        ProductList = new List<Product>();
        ProductVersionsList = new List<ProductVersion>();
        EnviromentList = new List<InstallationEnvironment>();
        content = new Content();
    }

    [Required]
    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Browser version Info.")]
    public string BrowserInfo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Database Version")]
    public string DatabaseVersion { get; set; }

    public Content content { get; set; }

}
```

The problem is that the values that reach the Controller are NULL even if you enter some value in them.

Comment: Is your model argument null, or all of its properties null?

Comment: No, not all the properties are null, just "Subject", "BroswerInfo" and "DatabaseVersion", they are null when they reach the Controller.

Comment: So are some values from your view being posted correctly? Are you showing just a sample of your code?

Comment: @Chris Hardie  Yes I'm showing a sample, the entire code is very large to post here but it's the same thing, just more fields, the Description field is posted properly to the Controller, however properties like "SUbject", "BrowserInfo" and "Database Version" reach null in the Controller, all these 3 properties happen to be crated using the TextBoxFor helper so I don't' know if that makes any difference.

Comment: Are you familiar enough with your browser's developer tools to check out your posted form variables?

Comment: @Chris Hardie Yea I use Firebug on Firefox, what do you want me to check?

Comment: If memory serves, there is a Net tab you should keep open when you post your page. Expand the post to your page and all your form variables and values should be in there.

Comment: @Chris Hardie It kinda tells me the same thing as when I check the model object in Debug mode, the values are somehow lost when they reach the controller, I don't get it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40761/discussion-between-eric-bergman-and-chris-hardie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your browser's developer tools to see if the form is properly posting its values. If it isn't, you should do two things:

A) Disabled javascript to see if there is a script that is interfering with the POST (typically either by disabling or clearing fields)

B) Ensuring your markup is valid using the W3C markup validation service

Comment: Thank you Chris, you are right I have disabled Java Script and found that the values were posted back to the server so the problem is happening on the client, I'm not sure exactly what is causing this problem but at least it led me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

For input fields use

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Subject)
```

For display fields use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Subject)
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Just noticed that you have Html.AntiForgeryToken() in the form. Make sure that you decorate your Post action method with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken].

Comment: Is that a solution or an improvement because it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Html.AntiForgeryToken puts a hidden token in the form. When the form posts back to the server, the framework compares it against a server-side copy. If you don't put [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] on your post method, then it won't use the token.